# Populate Spinner from first column in multidimensional array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, android-spinner

I'm trying to populate a spinner from a multidimensional array.  However when I run the app now I get this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

I guess I'm not sure how to put the data from the first column of my array into the spinner.

```
 //This method loads test scores into an array and populates spinner
    public void nameArrayListMethod (){

        InputStreamReader InputSR = null;
        BufferedReader BufferedRdr = null;
        String thisLine = null;

        AssetManager am = getAssets();

        try {
            InputSR = new InputStreamReader(am.open("scoresdata/test_scores.txt"));
            BufferedRdr = new BufferedReader(InputSR);

            // open input stream test_scores for reading purpose.
            int i = 0;
            while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(thisLine);

                String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
                testScoreList[i][0] = parts[0];
                testScoreList[i][1] = parts[1];
                i = i +1;
            }
            BufferedRdr.close();
            InputSR.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, testScoreList[0]);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    }
```

Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Name"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Math Grade"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="English Grade"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Grade"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Grade"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the text file:

```
Clarkson 43.2 75.6
Hammond 55.2 77.3
May 82.5 80.9
```

Now it seems to be partially working however it is populating the spinner with the first row not the first column.  How do I make it populate using the column?

Thanks,

Airfix

Comment: Please share the layout file for your activity

Comment: 0x0nosugar thanks, that hint showed me my silly error in calling the spinner iwthout a layout associated.  However I've updated my post with the actual error message.

Comment: That's a NullPointerException (...) OK, which line? And did you ever print anything by "System.out.println(thisLine);"?

Comment: Yes it printed out the the text file lines. I'm not sure what you mean by which line?  It was a FATAL EXCEPTION: main. I'm assuming in reference to my new ArrayAdapter line.  I'll bet it didn't like the testScoreList[0]

Comment: When I run the code line by line, it doesn't crash until the very last line of code where I set the spinner.  It has got to be something to do with multidimensional array I'm using.  I'm pretty sure the array is populated, I've tested that in other code.

Comment: Sorry I can't find the problem. I just used your code snippet in one of my apps and it worked fine. With a testscorelist like {"Hello", "Hallo", "world", "Welt"}. I think there's really some problem with your list. But I've no crystal ball :(    So all I can say is 'good luck'

Comment: Have you tried logging testScoreList[0] inside or after the while loop? And testScoreList[0][0] , testScoreList[0][1] to see the values? Something could be null, maybe if one line only contains one word and can't be split, for example

Comment: Yes it is populated.  When I print out the testScoreList array inside the while loop everything populates as expected.

Comment: It's funny I restarted android studio and now it seems to be partially working.  Might have been an issue with the API or the emulator I'm using?  Anyway now the problem is it is populating using the row, rather than the column.  I need it to show Clarkson, Hammond and May instead of Clarkson, 43.2, 75.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out.  I created a new array and used it in the while loop that essentially extracts the first column of the multidimensional array and used that as my spinner names.

Here is my code, it may not be pretty but it works.  Thanks 0X0nosugar for your help and pointing me in the right direction.

```
//This method loads test scores into an array and populates spinner
    public void nameArrayListMethod (){

        InputStreamReader InputSR = null;
        BufferedReader BufferedRdr = null;
        String thisLine = null;

        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        String[] SpinnerNames = new String[3];

        try {
            InputSR = new InputStreamReader(am.open("scoresdata/test_scores.txt"));
            BufferedRdr = new BufferedReader(InputSR);

            // open input stream test_scores for reading purpose.

            int i = 0;
            while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
                 //System.out.println(thisLine);

                String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
                testScoreList[i][0] = parts[0];
                testScoreList[i][1] = parts[1];
                testScoreList[i][2] = parts[2];

                SpinnerNames[i] = testScoreList[i][0]; //Extract first column for spinner
                //System.out.println(testScoreList[i][0] + " " + testScoreList [i][1] + " " + testScoreList[i][2]);
                                i = i +1;
            }
            BufferedRdr.close();
            InputSR.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, SpinnerNames);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    }
```

It's really satisfying when it finally works the way you want it to work.  Next task is to figure out how to make it work for a varying array size.

Thanks

Airfix